# Finishing current activity from a fragment

Tags: android

I have a fragment in an activity that I am using as a navigation drawer.  It contains buttons that when clicked start new activities (startActivity from a fragment simply calls startActivity on the current activity).

For the life of me I can't seem to figure out how I would finish the current activity after starting a new one.

I am looking to achieve something like this in the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (view == mButtonShows) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MyNewActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } 
}
```

But it seems Fragment.class does not implement finish() (like it implements startActivity(...)).

I would like the activity backstack cleared when they launch the 2nd activity. (so pressing back from the new activity would technically drop them back to the launcher)

Answer (score 337, accepted):

When working with fragments, instead of using `this` or refering to the context, always use `getActivity()`. You should call

### Java

```
getActivity().finish();
```

### Kotlin

```
activity.finish()
```

to finish your activity from fragment.

Comment: When working with fragments instead of using this or refering to the context, always us getActivity(); when working with fragments

Comment: `getActivity()` can be `null` in some cases. What should we do then?

Comment: @user983956 In such cases the activity is already destroyed, so just don't call `finish`.

Comment: As a tip : getActivity can be null if you try to use it before inflating the view

Comment: The Activity should be the controller/incharge not the fragment, you should rather callback the Activity though a callback interface and let the Activity decide if it should finish itself.

Comment: Though solutions works correctly, design wise its wrong. fragment should not decide any thing directly, related to parent activity. You should call interaction listener method, intimating that you wanted him(parent activity) to close. Then parent activity will save any data(if there) and closes by using finish().

Comment: Also, if you have singletons injected in the activity, do not forget to destroy them, it will create memory leaks, or if there are callbacks remove them ie. , 
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        getActivity().removeCallbacks();
        getActivity().destroy();       
    }

Comment: Use activity?.finish()

Comment: requireActivity().finish();

Answer (score 30):

Well actually...

I wouldn't have the Fragment try to finish the Activity.  That places too much authority on the Fragment in my opinion.  Instead, I would use the guide here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Have the Fragment define an interface which the Activity must implement.  Make a call up to the Activity, then let the Activity decide what to do with the information.  If the activity wishes to finish itself, then it can.

Comment: That's a good point, since a single activity can have multiple fragments present.  As you mention, the preferred way for a fragment to communicate back to its activity is via an interface.

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned by [Jon F Hancock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241204/jon-f-hancock), this is how a fragment can 'close' the activity by suggesting the activity to close.  This makes the fragment portable as is the reason for them.  If you use it in a different activity, you might not want to close the activity.

Code below is a snippet from an activity and fragment which has a save and cancel button.

PlayerActivity

```
public class PlayerActivity extends Activity 
    implements PlayerInfo.PlayerAddListener {

    public void onPlayerCancel() {
       // Decide if its suitable to close the activity, 
       //e.g. is an edit being done in one of the other fragments?
       finish();
    }
}
```

PlayerInfoFragment, which contains an interface which the calling activity needs to implement.

```
public class PlayerInfoFragment extends Fragment {
   private PlayerAddListener callback; // implemented in the Activity

   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
     super.onAttach(activity);
     callback= (PlayerAddListener) activity;
   }

   public interface PlayerAddListener {
       public void onPlayerSave(Player p); // not shown in impl above
       public void onPlayerCancel();
   }

   public void btnCancel(View v) {
      callback.onPlayerCancel(); // the activity's implementation
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This does not need assertion, Latest update in fragment in android JetPack

```
requireActivity().finish();
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use getActivity() method in order to finish the activity from the fragment.

```
getActivity().finish();
```

Answer (score 3):

**In Fragment** use getActivity.finishAffinity()

```
getActivity().finishAffinity();
```

**It will remove all the fragment which pushed by the current activity from the Stack with the Activity too...**

Comment: finishAffinity() will remove all the activities that have the same affinity, so activities below the current activity which contains the fragment in the stack could be finished as well.

Answer (score 2):

Every time I use finish to close the fragment, the entire activity closes. According to the docs, fragments should remain as long as the parent activity remains.

Instead, I found that I can change views back the the parent activity by using this statement:
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

This returns me back to the parent activity.

I hope that this helps someone else who may be looking for this.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple...

1- just grab activity by `getActivity()` in the fragment

2- then call `finish();`

So just `getActivity().finish();` will finish the parent activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. There shouldn't be any warning...

```
            Activity thisActivity = getActivity();
            if (thisActivity != null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(thisActivity, yourActivity.class)); // if needed
                thisActivity.finish();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for Java and Kotlin. However, logic of both ways are same. You should call **activity** after call **finish()** method.

> ***Answer for Kotlin***,

*If your activity cannot be null, use **Answer_1**. However, if your activity **can be null**, use **Answer_2**.*

```
Answer_1: activity!!.finish()
Answer_2: activity?.finish()
```

> ***Answer for Java,***

```
getActivity().finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
activity?.finish()
```

Comment: This was already posted [in June, 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62393957/354577)

Answer (score 0):

To finish activity in a Fragment use:

**getActivity().finish();**

Comment: This has already been answered. While answering old questions, only do post them if they provide a new solution, is novel and unique.

Answer (score -1):

[image: try to use this]

yes `Fragment.class` does not implement `finish()`

When working with fragments, instead of using this or refering to the context, always use `getActivity()`. You should call

Comment: Tell me the diference between your answer and the first answer above (by @coder_For_Life22)...

Comment: dont its a trap