# Finish the fragment while moving to other activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a main activity that contains 3 `fragments`. In each `fragment` I have a `listView`, on clicking which it is diverted to a new activity.

In the new `Activity`, I am changing the list view content that is clicked and diverting back to the main activity using intent.

This opens a new main Activity fragment and when I press back button I again get back to the previous Main Activity that was opened earlier.

Comment: call `getActivity().finish()` after you start your new activity intent from the fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finishing current activity from a fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907900/finishing-current-activity-from-a-fragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save activity's context in static variable like this

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public static MainActivity mainActivityInstance;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_staff_login);
            //finishing older loaded mainActivity 
            if(MainActivity.mainActivityInstance!=null){
               MainActivity.mainActivityInstance.finish();
            }
            mainActivityInstance=this;
    
        }
    }
```

From other activities you can finish your older activity like this

```
if(MainActivity.mainActivityInstance!=null){
     MainActivity.mainActivityInstance.finish();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using startActivity use startActivityForResult in your fragment and have onActivityResult to obtain result from new Activity you have started

In your fragment do like this

```
static final int NEXT_ACTIVITY = 100;

//insert in listview on click
Intent intent = new Intent(context,Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("key","value");//if needed
startActivityForResult(intent,NEXT_ACTIVITY);

@Override //*Note* you must override this method in you parent Activity in order to reflect the data inside your fragment
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);//while using inside fragment
switch(requestCode) {
case NEXT_ACTIVITY:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle res = data.getExtras();
        String result = res.getString("param_result");
        Log.d("FIRST", "result:"+result);
    }
    break;
}
}
```

In your new Activity while finishing/onBackpressed

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString("param_result", "Thanks Thanks");
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

For fragments, instead of `finish();`, you should call

```
getActivity().finish();
```