# How to end an activity on a fragment on Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, fragment

I am developing a movie application.

**My problem is this:**

When I click on the movie, it shows the details of it.
In the details I can watch the trailer. When you click the `Watch` button, it will be redirected to `YouTube`, where the movie trailer is displayed. But after clicking on another movie again, it opens YouTube directly instead of showing its details.

How can I finish the activity I created to redirect to YouTube?

My code:

> MovieListFragment

```
public class MovieListFragment extends Fragment implements OnMovieListener, OnBtnMoreListner {

//Adapter
private MovieListParentApdater movieListParentApdater;

//ViewModel
private MovieListViewModel movieListViewModel;

//ViewBinding
private MovieListFragmentBinding movieListFragmentBinding;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    movieListFragmentBinding = MovieListFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);

    movieListViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MovieListViewModel.class);

    configureRecyclerView();

    //Calling the observer
    observeGendersChange();

    return movieListFragmentBinding.getRoot();

}

 //Configure RecyclerView
    private void configureRecyclerView() {
        movieListParentApdater = new MovieListParentApdater(getActivity(),this,this);
        movieListFragmentBinding.rvParent.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        movieListFragmentBinding.rvParent.setAdapter(movieListParentApdater);

    }

//is called on my gridViewAdapter when I click on the image 
@Override
    public void onMovieClick(MovieModel movie) {  
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("movie", movie);
        Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(),R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.movieDetailsFragment,bundle);
    }
```

> MovieDetailsFragment

```
 public class MovieDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    //ViewBinding
    private MovieDetailsFragmentBinding movieDetailsFragmentBinding;

    //ViewModel
    private MovieDetailsViewModel movieDetailsViewModel;

    //Movie
    private MovieModel movie;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        movieDetailsFragmentBinding = MovieDetailsFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);

        movieDetailsViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MovieDetailsViewModel.class);

        movieDetailsFragmentBinding.btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigateUp();
            }
        });

        movie = getArguments().getParcelable("movie");

        observerUrlVideoMovieChange();

        //btn play video
        movieDetailsFragmentBinding.btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(movie.getVideo() == null) // if movie hasn't video
                    movieDetailsViewModel.getUrlVideoMoviesID(movie.getId()); //get url
                else
                    showVideo(movie.getVideo());
            }
        });

        //show details
        showDetails();

        return movieDetailsFragmentBinding.getRoot();
    }

 //show trailer movie
    private void showVideo(String videoId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoId));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

[Link Video](https://youtu.be/uD2YMGav-gg)

Comment: Could you attach your first fragment code from where you're invoking this MovieDetailsFragment fragment?

Comment: @VipulKumar Hi. Yes of course. I already updated my post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finishing current activity from a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907900/finishing-current-activity-from-a-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's the exact issue here but I can see you're trying to observe a liveData. Sometimes liveData may hold an old value depending on the lifecycle owner.

To check whether this is the case, try commenting all the other calls to *showVideo()* method except the one in *movieDetailsFragmentBinding.btnPlay.setOnClickListener()* method and remove if-else condition as well.